# MVC5 : How do I specify form-control to limit the number of decimal places?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, currency

I have following decimal field:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
```

In my Razor view

```
<td>Price</td>
<td>

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDecimal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control decimal-small inline" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyDecimal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</td>
```

I want that users can only put a max of 2 number behind the decimal seperator. In many post I see that the DisplayFormat should work but it doesn't do anything in edit mode. In my edit field I can still put more than 2 numbers behind the seperator

I also tried

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
```

Still no difference.

Comment: What about this `##.#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you expect different thing that the [DisplayFormat] attribute does. This attribute says, how the data should be **DISPLAYED**, not entered.
Your solution works, and your number is displayed with applied formatting, isn't it?
What you're trying to achieve is an **input mask**, which is a client-side feature. See the following links to find out more about it:

- [How to implement input masking with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100838/how-to-implement-input-masking-with-asp-net-mvc)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642477/Input-Masking-in-MVC-using-Data-Annotation
- [Input mask MVC unmask in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531320/input-mask-mvc-unmask-in-controller)

**Edit:**

I've performed a quick test
ViewModel:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Test {
            get { return (decimal) 1.345; } }
```

and view :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control decimal-small inline" } })
```

and it shows:
[image]

**As an alternative, you could try:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Test,"{0:0.00}")
```

Comment: It also doesn't display correct. In my model the value is 1.345. According to your anwser I should see 1.34 but I see the entire number

Comment: I have tried your example and I found the problem. There was some js script that was setting the value of my model field. So I have put a regex attribute with format for input mask and now it's working. Thx!